# Does AWS have man pages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am studying for my AWS certificate. I SSH into an Amazon Linux EC2.

When I type `man aws` or `man ec2` I don't get any results.

I have seen the AWS CLI website but I wonder why there aren't man pages for AWS.

Comment: Not that i know of, it's a separate set of documentation to upkeep, not worth the effort. The CLI is extensively documented and provides help functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You invoke it through CLI. For example:

```
$ aws ec2 help
```

for help on AWS CLI ec2 commands.

Output:

> NAME
>          ec2 -
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Amazon  Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) provides resizable computing
>          capacity in the Amazon Web Services (AWS) cloud. Using Amazon EC2 elim-
>          inates your need to invest in hardware up front, so you can develop and
>          deploy applications faster.
>
> AVAILABLE COMMANDS
>
> ```
>    o accept-reserved-instances-exchange-quote
>
>    o accept-vpc-peering-connection
>
>    o allocate-address
> ```

---

If you want help on subcommands:

```
$ aws ec2 create-image help
```

> NAME
>          create-image -
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Creates  an  Amazon  EBS-backed  AMI from an Amazon EBS-backed instance
>          that is either running or stopped.
>
> ```
>    If you customized your instance with instance store volumes or EBS vol-
>    umes  in addition to the root device volume, the new AMI contains block
>    device mapping information  for  those  volumes.  When  you  launch  an
>    instance  from  this  new AMI, the instance automatically launches with
>    those additional volumes.
> ```